# I cannot figure out why python has given me a type error

Tags: typeerror

I want to make a circle with a color parameter but it gives me a type error when I try to do so, I don't know if I am missing anything obvious because I am new to programming, thanks in advance.

> Error: `TypeError: begin_fill() takes exactly 0 positional argument(s)
>   (1 given) on line 6`

Here is the code

```
import turtle

def colour_choice(color_choice):
  turtle.color(color_choice)
  turtle.fillcolor(color_choice)
  turtle.begin_fill(color_choice)
  turtle.circle(25)
  penup()
  forward(50)
  pendown()

colour_choice("Blue")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven’t worked with Turtle before, but it looks like the begin_fill method doesn’t take an argument. Try removing it (color_choice) and see if it fixes the issue.

```
import turtle

def colour_choice(color_choice):
  turtle.color(color_choice)
  turtle.fillcolor(color_choice)
  turtle.begin_fill()
  turtle.circle(25)
  penup()
  forward(50)
  pendown()

colour_choice("Blue")
```

You can find the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.begin_fill

Comment: Thank you, I made some slight alterations but nothing too serious, you saved me a few hours of frustration.